# Loop integration, Can loops be triple nested?

Tags: python, loops, pygame, nested-loops

What this program is supposed to do is once the pygame window is opened with the image, coordinates from a mouse click on the window are grabbed and used into a loop that changes and sets the rgb values to a "negated effect" in a scaled region.

My question related to how these loops can be integrated to function to its intended purpose?

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

simage = pygame.image.load(sys.argv[1]) #retrieve image from command arg
(w, h) = simage.get_size() 
window = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
window.blit(simage, (0,0))
a = 0
b = 0


for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mouse_presses = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if mouse_presses[0]:
            print("mouse")
            (a, b) = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
        
for y in range(a, a*10):
    for x in range(b, b*10):
        (r, g, b, _) = simage.get_at((x, y)) 
        simage.set_at((x, y), 255-r, 255-g, 255-b)  
pygame.display.update() 


while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle all the event in an event loop inside the application loop. The events are continuously queried in the application loop.
Get the position from the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event (`event.pos`) and change the color of the image around this position.
Redraw the image in the application loop:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

simage = pygame.image.load(sys.argv[1]) #retrieve image from command arg
w, h = simage.get_size() 
window = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()    

run = True
while run: 
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x0, y0 = event.pos
            for y in range(y0-5, y0+5):
                for x in range(x0-5, x0+5):
                    if 0 <= x < w and 0 <= y < h:
                        r, g, b, _ = simage.get_at((x, y)) 
                        simage.set_at((x, y), (255-r, 255-g, 255-b))  

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(simage, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update() 

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: bro tysm makes total sense